# Merge entities in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have these entities which represent `Menu` and `Labels` SQL tables:

```
public class Menu
{        
    public int IdMenu { get; set; }
    public int IdLabel { get; set; }
}

public class Label
{        
    public int IdLabel { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In a controller I have this method:

```
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var menu = _service.GetAll();
    var model = _mapper.Map<IList<MenuModel>>(menu);
    return Ok(model);
}
```

but obviously, it gives me only `IdMenu` and `IdLabel` for each menu item.

What should I do to let it give me `IdMenu` and Value of `Label`?

---

**Update n. 1:**

Entities:

```
public class MenuPadre_EL
{
    [Key]
    public int IdMenuPadre { get; set; }
    public int IdEtichetta { get; set; }
    public string Icona { get; set; }

    public MenuPadreUtente_EL menuPadreUtente { get; set; }
}

public class MenuPadreUtente_EL
{        
    public int IdMenuPadreUtente { get; set; }
    public int IdUtente { get; set; }

    public int IdMenuPadre { get; set; }
    public MenuPadre_EL menuPadre { get; set; }
}
```

DataContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Etichetta>().HasKey(e => new { e.IdEtichetta, e.Lingua });
    modelBuilder.Entity<MenuPadreUtente_EL>().HasKey(m => new { m.IdMenuPadre, m.IdUtente });
    modelBuilder.Entity<MenuPadre_EL>()
        .HasOne(mpu => mpu.menuPadreUtente)
        .WithOne(mp => mp.menuPadre)
        .HasForeignKey<MenuPadreUtente_EL>(mpu => mpu.IdMenuPadre);
}
```

Model:

```
public class MenuPadreUtente_ELModel
{
    public int IdMenuPadreUtente { get; set; }
    public int IdMenuPadre { get; set; }
    public int IdUtente { get; set; }
    public string Etichetta { get; set; }
    public MenuPadre_EL menuPadre { get; set; }
}
```

API Output:

```
[
    {
        "idMenuPadreUtente": 1,
        "idMenuPadre": 1,
        "idUtente": 1,
        "etichetta": null,
        "menuPadre": null
    }
]
```

why `menuPadre` is null?

Comment: You need to look up Entity Framework relationship configuration and *.Include* from the Linq documentation.

Comment: Agreed.  And the code has no relationship properties between them.

Comment: @NeilW  I've updated original question: look at **Update n. 1**

Comment: You are missing "naviation" properties. (how the 2 items relate to one another). see https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/ef-core-relationships-navigation-properties/. "public virtual Department Department { get; set; }" and "public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }" are the navigation properties in that example.

Comment: @granadaCoder so what changes should I make to my code? There's nothing different from the example in your link

Comment: Finally I solved. It was enough to add `.Include` when getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as bellow:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var menu = menueList();
    var lable = lableList();
    var model = (from _menue in menu
                join _lable in lable
                on _menue.IdLabel equals _lable.IdLabel

                select new
                {
                    IdMenu = _menue.IdMenu,
                    Value = _lable.Value,
                    
                }).ToList();

    return Ok(model);
}
```